# Merge operation is occupying full RAM

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 20 CSV files having a maximum size of 1 GB. In all these files, there are only two common columns "X", "Y". I am trying to merge these files on ["X", "Y"] to get a single file with all the columns. But, while doing so, I am getting **MemoryError** after merging 10 files.
Please help me to find a solution.
Please find the below specifications:

```
RAM: 504 GB
CPU: 160 Core
Python Version: 3.7.0
Pandas Version: 0.23.4
```

Sample Code:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    if final_df.empty:
        final_df = df
    else:
        final_df = final_df.merge(df, on = ["X","Y"], how = "left")
return final_df
```

Comment: Your data frames usually take less memory than the csv's. You should definitely post your merge code here.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to free up memory manually with garbage collector "gc.collect()"? You can do it at the end of each loop, like this:

```
import gc

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    if final_df.empty:
        final_df = df
    else:
        final_df = final_df.merge(df, on = ["X","Y"], how = "left")

    gc.collect()

return final_df
```